# How to enforce compile-time checking of constructor in Typescript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, dependency-injection, abstract-class, aurelia

is there a way i can enforce compile-time checking of constructor existence in Typescript?
ie.
I have the following class:

```
@autoinject
export abstract class HttpServiceBase {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
}
```

and then I have the following class:

```
export class UserService extends HttpServiceBase{
    public async getAllUsers():Promise<any>{
        ... this function is not important here
    }
}

@autoinject
export class NewUserViewModel {
    public model:any;
    constructor(private service:UserService){}

     public async activate(){
          return  this.service.getAllUsers()
                .then(result=> this.model = result);
      }
 }
```

The problem here is that the base abstract class has constructor with 1 parameter, bud the subclass does not have a constructor exposed. So I get run-time errors when Aurelia tries to construct the UserService from DI container. I haven't found a way to tell the compiler to throw an error when I forget to write the sub-class constructor if the super-class has required parameters in it's own.

**Update**:
this scenario works without problem:

```
@autoinject
export class UserService extends HttpServiceBase{
    constructor(httpClient:HttpClient){
        super(httpClient);
    }
    public async getAllUsers():Promise<any>{
    ... this function is not important here
    }
}
```

But I have many services like this, and many team members. So there is plenty of points where compiler should notify for base constructor hiding.

Comment: If you get runtime errors because something is being treated like no-arg constructor when it is not one, then my guess is that whatever accepts or decorates `UserService` isn't strongly typed enough.  It should be declared so that it only accepts something of type `new()=>any`.  What exactly is consuming `UserService`, and what are its declared typings?  (Maybe someone with Aurelia experience can answer this)

Comment: Ok, I have added an usage example (NewUserViewModel).
The problem is when I try to issue a httpclient call because httpclient is undefined, because DI container hasn't constructed the object graph correctly because of the missing constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the typings for what is consuming the class constructor *value* `UserService`, whose type is `typeof UserService`.  It's probably something in the Aurelia library.  For all I know it's just the `@autoinject` decorator, but that doesn't seem to have been done on `UserService`.

Comment: Yes, autoinject is a decorator from Aurelia framework, I could use inject(HttpClient) instead, but I prefer autoinject. It tells Aurelia to inject dependencies in the constructor. The problem I have is with typescript compiler/vs code not telling me that I should implement constructor on my subclass too. If I put the constructor(httpClient:HttpClient){base(httpClient)} into UserService then all works without problem. But the thing is I forget to do so mostly of the time, and I have a large number of services.

Comment: If a subclass doesn't define a constructor, it should implicitly get a constructor that calls the super constructor.  I don't know what Aurelia is doing, but I wonder if the real problem is just that the subclass didn't have `@autoinject`.  What happens if `UserService` has `@autoinject` but no declared constructor?

Comment: It is the same, it works only if I put the constructor.